# storing arabic in mysql using PHP convert text to u0645u0631u062du0628u0627

Tags: php, mysql

I want to store arabic in mysql database but when I execute query it convert arabic to some numbers like `u0645u0631u062du0628u0627`

when I print this query in which $datas='hello'

```
insert into taxi_notification(user_id,message,datetime,type) 
    values(".$user_id.",'".$datas."',NOW(),'".$type."');
```

it converts it to

```
insert into taxi_notification(user_id,message,datetime,type) 
    values(1965,'\u0645\u0631\u062d\u0628\u0627',NOW(),'admin_notification')
```

I want to store Arabic string as it display in browser

Comment: Please read [utf-8 all the way through](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through) It may well answer your question

Comment: **ALSO** Your script is wide open to [SQL Injection Attack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)
Even [if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string)
Use [prepared parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) in either the `MYSQLI_` or `PDO` API's

Answer (score 0):

You must have to change your **collation** as **utf8_general_ci**.

[image]